# add new column into an existing table and add column title

Tags: r

I have an existing table read from a csv file, which is like

```
Ab<-read.table(“Ab.csv”,sep=”,”,header=T)
```

I have another column, like

```
New_column<-rep(0,10)
```

How to add this `New_column`into the existing table `Ab`, and how to add a column title for this added column in the modified table?

Comment: `Ab$New_column <- New_Column`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cbind() function will do the trick:

Ab2 <- cbind(Ab, New_column)

This retains the columns names that were in Ab, from the CSV file.  It names the new column "New_column".  If that isn't the column name you want, specify it in cbind.  Say you wanted to name the new column "values":

Ab2 <- cbind(Ab, values= New_column)

You can also rename later, using the names() function:

names(Ab2) <- c("first_col_name", "second_col_name", "values")

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Ab$New_column = rep(0,10)
```